# holes in masonry / isotope layout

Tags: jquery, masonry, jquery-isotope

I do not understand why my isotope layout doesn't work?
There are holes in the layout, when there is not supposed to be ?
What am I doing wrong ?

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/options.html#percentposition

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

var $grid = $('.portfolio').isotope({
              percentPosition: true,
    layoutMode: 'masonry',
              itemSelector: '.item',

              masonry: {
                columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
              }
            })

});
```

See codepen : http://codepen.io/ifeltblankk/pen/LxqXVW

And why, with the same code, it works on codepen, and not on the website... http://clients.studio24-24.com/veronika/isotope/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $grid = $('.portfolio').isotope({
    layoutMode: 'masonry'
  })
});
```

```css
.portfolio .item img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.item {
  width: 24%;
  background: #e6e5e4;
}

.grid-sizer,
.item {
  width: 24%;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//npmcdn.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<div class="portfolio">

  <div class="n1 item">
    <img class="w-20 p-10" src="http://clients.studio24-24.com/veronika/isotope/images/Daniel-Peace-x-Lusty-Ice-x-Effy-Nails-03.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="n2 item">
    <img class="w-20 p-10" src="http://clients.studio24-24.com/veronika/isotope/images/Henrike-Stahl-The-Forumist-02.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="n3 item">
    <img class=" w-30 p-10" src="http://clients.studio24-24.com/veronika/isotope/images/Henrike-Stahl-The-Forumist-09.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="n1 item">
    <img class="w-40 p-10" src="http://clients.studio24-24.com/veronika/isotope/images/Wilkosz&Way-SLEEK-Magazine-01.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="n1 item">
    <img class="w-30 p-10" src="Par-hasard-studio-paris-design-graphique-logo-05.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="n2 item">
    <img class=" w-30 p-10" src="http://clients.studio24-24.com/veronika/isotope/images/Joana-Krawczyk-Eclectic-&-Less-Magazine-14.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="n2 item">
    <img class="w-30 p-10" src="http://clients.studio24-24.com/veronika/isotope/images/Par-hasard-studio-paris-design-graphique-logo-03.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="n2 item">
    <img class="w-30 p-10" src="http://clients.studio24-24.com/veronika/isotope/images/Joana-Krawczyk-Eclectic-&-Less-Magazine-01.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="n1 item">
    <img class="w-20 p-10" src="http://clients.studio24-24.com/veronika/isotope/images/Daniel-Peace-x-Lusty-Ice-x-Effy-Nails-03.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="n2 item">
    <img class="w-20 p-10" src="http://clients.studio24-24.com/veronika/isotope/images/Henrike-Stahl-The-Forumist-02.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="n3 item">
    <img class=" w-30 p-10" src="http://clients.studio24-24.com/veronika/isotope/images/Henrike-Stahl-The-Forumist-09.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="n1 item">
    <img class="w-40 p-10" src="http://clients.studio24-24.com/veronika/isotope/images/Wilkosz&Way-SLEEK-Magazine-01.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="n1 item">
    <img class="w-30 p-10" src="http://clients.studio24-24.com/veronika/isotope/images/Lucio-Aru-&-Franco-Erre-Eclectic Magazine-07.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="n2 item">
    <img class=" w-30 p-10" src="http://clients.studio24-24.com/veronika/isotope/images/Joana-Krawczyk-Eclectic-&-Less-Magazine-14.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="n2 item">
    <img class="w-30 p-10" src="http://clients.studio24-24.com/veronika/isotope/images/Joana-Krawczyk-Eclectic-&-Less-Magazine-09.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="n2 item">
    <img class="w-30 p-10" src="http://clients.studio24-24.com/veronika/isotope/images/Joana-Krawczyk-Eclectic-&-Less-Magazine-01.jpg" alt="">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually want to use both, because I want then to have a filter on items (that I managed to make it work here : http://clients.studio24-24.com/veronika/shadertoy-com-tost/
but the layout is not working on this one....

I made the changes that you suggested,and it works, but then i have to add the filtering from isotope :/ ...

http://codepen.io/ifeltblankk/pen/ygZGvz

Comment: Thank you! I don't understand why it's not working on codepen... super weird..

http://codepen.io/ifeltblankk/pen/oBmJaR

Comment: Ok, i made it work on the codepen, it was the order of the plugins!
I'll try to make it work on the page now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Made it work on the html page aswell, still don't understand why it wasn't working... http://clients.studio24-24.com/veronika/isotope/